# after update on VS 2012, the automatic event creation doesn't works

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a old project started with VS 2002. Time after time I updated my project on the last VS version (2003, 2005, 2008, 2010 and 2012). Now my poejct is on last version of VS (2012) and I have some strange behavior. When I put a button in design mode, previously when I double clicked on it, the system generated automatically the event I redirect me on code page on the sub event. Now it doesn't work. I have to go on the click event property part and click on name of event.

The other strange behavior is since my update in VS 2008, I never have designer file in my project. My rpoject compile without errors but I have no designer file into my project.

If I create new project in VS 2012, the doucble click event geenrate the event into code page and designer file exist.

How I can fix it ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This might be hard but you could start with a new project and port your code and design to it.
The problem your are getting is because of missing assemblies.